# Vuetify.js - <v-text-field> inside <v-menu> can't be focused without <v-menu> disappearing

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Consider the following layout:

```
<v-menu>
    <span slot="activator">Open dropdown</span>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 1</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 2</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 3</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-text-field label="Search" append-icon="search"></v-text-field></v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

This renders a "button" to open a dropdown menu, with 3 menu items and a text input field for search as the 4th item. The issue is that focusing on the text field automatically collapses the menu. All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `@click` to `@click.stop` on last `v-list-tile` I guess

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - `@click` shouldn't even be present for the last `v-list-tile` item, a copying error.

Comment: Still, you can use it I think. `@click.stop=""`

Comment: Nevertheless, `@click.stop` solves the issue and is the correct answer, thanks a bunch @Traxo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  `:close-on-click="false"` or  `:close-on-content-click="false"`

```
<v-menu  :close-on-content-click="false"  :close-on-click="false">
    <span slot="activator">Open dropdown</span>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 1</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 2</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-list-tile-title>Menu item 3</v-list-tile-title></v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click=""><v-text-field label="Search" append-icon="search"></v-text-field></v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not working with the thing I needed that for for more than a year now, but anyways. Also, is this something that was added to Vuetify recently, less than one and a half years ago?